# PHP bind/show specific record in textarea

Tags: php, sms, dreamweaver

using DW CS6, I have a dynamic table in admin_inquiry.php, which displays rows of records. One of which is the Contact No, which is a link.

```
<td>
    <a href="admin_sms.php?ContactNo=<?php echo $row_ContactUs['ContactNo'];?>">Send SMS</a>
</td>
```

When that is clicked, it goes to a new page, admin_sms.php, and it displays the corresponding contact no in a textfield.

```
<input name='number' type='text' id="number" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['ContactNo'])){echo $_GET['ContactNo'];}else{echo "";}?>">
```

My problem is, I also want to display the 'message' along with the 'ContactNo' in a textarea,kinda like what is displayed when sending emails,you can see the message and sender at the top. But also show only the 'ContactNo' on a separate textfield. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Where does the message come from?

Comment: @Barmar In the first page, admin_inquiry.php It is displayed in the dynamic table

Comment: You can do it with Javascript. When clicking on the anchor, get the message from the input field, and add it to the `href` URL, e.g. `this.href += '&message=' + encodeURIComponent(message)`.

Comment: @Barmar could you try to answer sir. I'm not familiar with the method but I  can try your idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it with jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var message = $("#msg").val();
    this.href += '&message=' + encodeURIComponent(message);
});
```

Then in the admin_sms.php script, you use `$_GET['message']` to get the message to send.

Comment: Should I put that jQuery in the admin_inquiry page? and in the admin_sms page, like this?
<textarea name="frmMsg" cols="45" rows="5" id="frmMsg"><?php if(isset($_GET['message'])){echo $_GET['message'];}else{echo "";}?>
  </textarea>

Comment: Hi I kinda got it using session. but it only shows the same message. When I click a diff link it should show the corresponding message that belongs to that particular id or contact no in my case

Comment: This answer assumes there's just a single text field with `id="msg"`. If you have multiple messages fields, and want each link to send the corresponding message, you'll need to use a class and DOM traversal functions to grab the right message.